# Cannot display label and field on same line using django-crispy forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to place the label of my fields on the left side of the form with the right side having the text input. However, I can't seem to make it work. Here are the settings i've placed.

forms.py

```
helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('test_field'),
    FormActions(
        Submit('submit', 'Record', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
        Reset('reset', 'Clear', css_class='btn btn-default'),
    )
)
```

form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block page_panel %}
{% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

The resulting html is like this
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyaji.png)

Comment: You don't need the form_class = 'form-horizontal'

Answer (score 4):

In your example you're trying to implement a Bootstrap [form-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal). To do this correctly you need to add helper classes to the label and form input [per the docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms).

Try this to make `form-horizontal` work, for instance:

```
helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
helper.layout = Layout(
    Field('test_field'),
    FormActions(
        Submit('submit', 'Record', css_class='btn btn-primary'),
        Reset('reset', 'Clear', css_class='btn btn-default'),
    )
)
```

You can adjust your column sizes as necessary.

Another option for a slightly different layout (also with label at the same level as the input vs. above it) would be to use Bootstrap's [`form-inline`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) which would require [different config using Django crispy forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-inline-forms).

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get it to work either until I added the following to the **settings.py**:

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me with django-crispy-forms was using the helper attribute `form_style = 'inline'`.